# Добавление файлов за несколько раз

Tags: javascript

Отправляю файлы через input type="file", FormData. Нажимаю на input, выбираю один файл - все нормально. Нажимаю повторно на input, выбираю еще один файл. Но старый выбранный файл затирается, те его замещает новый файл. А мне нужно, чтобы происходило не замещение, а дополнение. Пытаюсь сохранять старый файл в переменную. Но это не дает результата. Сохранить нормально файл в переменную не получается. Как решить проблему?

```
<input type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" multiple id="new-homework" value="Выберите файлы">


var files;
var nf_button = document.getElementById("new-homework");
nf_button.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(files) {
        files = files + nf_button.files;
        console.log(files); 
    }
    else
        files = nf_button.files;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var files = [];
...
  for (var i = 0; i < nf_button.files.length; i++) { 
    files.push(nf_button.files[i]);
  }
```

---

На 24 вопроса - один принятый ответ? Вам скоро прекратят отвечать.